# Expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined - React Native Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, supabase

I am **extremely** new to `React Native` and keep running into errors. Coming from `Flutter`, I have no idea how to handle some of these errors. Right now I have two screens with their own navigation stacks and `App.js` shows one of them depending on if the user is logged in or not. I am getting the error below whenever I try to build the app. I don't see anything in `LoginScreen` that should be causing this, but the error suggests there is something, so I need help.

**Error**

```
 ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `LoginScreen`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by LoginScreen)
    in LoginScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by AuthScreenStack)
    in AuthScreenStack (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { supabase, session } from "./src/supabaseClient"
import { TabBarStack } from "./screens/Main/TabBarView"
import { AuthScreenStack } from "./screens/Auth/AuthStack"

export default function App() {
  console.log("Here we go");

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoating] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(session);
    setAuth(session);

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      console.log(session);
      setAuth(session);
    });

  });

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {auth ? <TabBarStack /> : <AuthScreenStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**AuthStack.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, Layout, Image } from "react-native";

const isRegister = false;

function LoginScreen() {
console.log('auth');

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Layout flexDirection='row'>
            <Image source={require('../../assets/icon.png')}/>
            <Text>GLOBE</Text>
        </Layout>
    </View> 
    );
}

const AuthStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export function AuthScreenStack() {
    return (
        <AuthStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
            <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

Comment: You should be able to see the error as you code if you start using Typescript instead of JavaScript. I'm sure you will love it if you come from Flutter world!

Comment: I did see that as an option when creating the project, but most tutorials I have found use JavaScript. How is Typescript an easier switch from Flutter? This switch is difficult because issues were automatically underlined in red when I was using Flutter in Android Studio, even before I ran the code. With React Native I have to wait for errors to show after building and they aren't as clear.

Comment: If you use Typescript, you will see the errors high lighted in red underline before running the code just like you used to in Flutter.